# Manipulating dom elements dynamically in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

I am trying to have a button change color when the user clicks it in React. Each button I am trying to add this functionality to is also updating state. How can I interact with styles AND update state when these buttons are clicked? Here's my crude attempt:

Some HTML:

```
<div className="searchPrivacyContainer">
            <p>USERS CAN SEARCH FOR MY PROJECT:</p>
            <div className="searchPrivacySelect">
              <div
                className="searchPrivacyYes"
                onClick={
                  (holdColor,
                  function () {
                    setProposal({ ...proposal, searchable: true });
                  })
                }
              >
```

And this is the most basic version of the function I'm trying to bind. Writing the body of the function should be the straightforward part hopefully, I just don't know how to bind it to the div which is already calling another function:

```
const holdColor = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.style);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this part isn't not working as you expecting,

```
onClick = {
  (holdColor,
    function() {
      setProposal({ ...proposal,
        searchable: true
      });
    })
}
```

Simple test,

```js
function x(ev){console.log('x', ev)}
function y(ev){console.log('y', ev)}

const listener = (x, y)

listener(123)
```

Look, first one (`x`) never got called, So, you might wanna do something like this on your listener.

```
onClick={(ev) => {
  holdColor(ev)

  setProposal({ ...proposal,
    searchable: true
  });
}}
```

EDIT:
see this working example (it might be helpful),  https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-wilson-drbbk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thank you for this! I have tried it that way, but React will not let me call/invoke a function in this context (i.e. holdColor(ev)). It will only let me bind it (i.e. holdColor) without invoking it.

Comment: you dont need to bind anymore, as its a arrow function see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Comment: `React will not let me call/invoke a function in this context` i didn't get it

Comment: @user72503948573038 pls, mark as answer & upvote if it helped